# Highcharts datetime tick start and interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization

The data starts at 6am on Monday and has a data point for each hour. I am having trouble getting the xAxis tick marks to read "6am Monday", and repeat every 24 hours.

Any tips? Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4x136qxg/1/

[image: highcharts work in progress]

Here is my main graphing function:

```
var dayInMilliseconds = 3600 * 1000 * 24;    

$(function () {
    $('#chart1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Orders'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                // month: '%A',
            },
            // tickInterval: dayInMilliseconds,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 3
            },
            // startOnTick: true,
            // endOnTick: true,
            // min: 1413352800000,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            min: 0,
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle'
                },
                lineWidth: 0,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                // pointStart: 1413352800000,
            },
        },    

        series: [{
            name: '1',
            color: '#edc54b',
            data: seriesData[0].data
        },{
            name: '2',
            color: '#edc54b',
            data: seriesData[1].data
        },{
            name: '3',
            color: '#edc54b',
            data: seriesData[2].data
        },{
            name: '4',
            color: '#edc54b',
            data: seriesData[3].data
        },{
            name: '5',
            color: '#edc54b',
            data: seriesData[4].data
        },{
            name: '6',
            color: '#edc54b',
            data: seriesData[5].data
        },{
            name: '7',
            color: '#fbd046',
            data: seriesData[6].data
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: How your seriesData looks like? Can you update http://jsfiddle.net/4x136qxg/ with data, to recreate entire chart?

Comment: Updated your jsfiddle @SebastianBochan

Comment: You have a timestamp like "1413352800000" which is first, run function new Date(1413352800000) and you will notice that its returns "Wed Oct 15 2014 08:00:00 GMT" time, so its converted and then its printed correct. You can use offset http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.timezoneOffset / try to disable UTC http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC